# How to use event argument outside the event

Tags: c#, events, arguments

I'm trying to create a custom download app. Its all working except for the download all button that cant pick up the "percent1" variable from the "DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs". I have instantiated it prior to the mainForm constructor but it wont read the changed value.

Here's the code, partially stripped since most of it isnt relevant to the question:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
//Variables (not all, just the one im having issues with)
    private double percentage1;

//Main form constructor
    public Main(){...}

//Download File Async custom method
    public void DldFile(string url, string fileName, string localPath, AsyncCompletedEventHandler completedName, DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler progressName)
    {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), localPath + "\\" + fileName);
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(completedName);
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(progressName);
    }

//Button 1 click event to start download
    private void btnDld1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (url1 != "" && Directory.Exists(localPath1))
        {
            _startDate1 = DateTime.Now;
            DldFile(url1, fileName1, localPath1, completed1, progress1);
        }
        //took out the try/catch, other ifs to try and cut it down
    }

//Download Progress Changed event for Download 1
    public void progress1(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        percentage1 = e.ProgressPercentage; //THIS IS WHERE I WAS EXPECTING TO UPDATE "percentage1"
        progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage1).ToString());
    }

//Button that starts all downloads click event where all my problems are at the moment
    private void btnDldAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //The progress bar that should let me know the global status for all webClients
        progressBarAll.Value = (
            int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage1).ToString()) + //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
            int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage2).ToString()) + //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
            int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage3).ToString()) + //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
            int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage4).ToString()) + //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
            int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage5).ToString())) / 5; //HERE IS MY PROBLEM

        //Checks if the link exists and starts it from the download button click event
        if (url1 != "")
        {
            btnDld1.PerformClick();
        }
        //Continues for url2, 3, 4, 5 and else
    }
}
```

So this is the shortest way i found of letting you know what im trying to pull off, if there's something missing please let me know, i'll try to add any info as fast as possible.

I have tried to instantiate "progress1" to try and acess its percentage1 variable, but it didnt work. I've tried doing the same thing with the webClient but didnt work either. I have used google and stackflow search to no avail. So im not sure if the question is too dumb, or there's a diferent way to look at the issue thats completely out of my mindset.

So main problem is updating the "percentage1" variable and using it.
There are other problems regarding the "progressBarAll.Value" calculation that will be solved when i can get my hands on the right value. So no need to worry about that if you see it.

Comment: Well thats a good question, i didnt want to add it so this post was directed to one problem only, then i'd try to figure that out further on. But the idea was to keep the `progressBarAll` updated according to whatever download was running. If dld1 is in progress then it would display download1 progress, if more then 1 was working it would display the average of all working downloads. But i guess i can pull that off once i get a hanlde on the e.Percentage value outside the event handler.

Comment: How exactly is it not working, is the DownloadProgressChanged event never fired, or the variable never assigned? Try putting a breakpoint on `progress1()` and see if it is hit. Then debug it step-by-step to trace down the actual problem. You're not doing anything wrong here as far as I can tell, and you should be able to set percentage1 from the event handler without problems.

Comment: @Aevitas - Well i set the breakpoint as you said and what i saw left me even more confused, something wierd is happening. When i click download all the event handler is fired. But the variable `percentage1` has a diferent value then the `e.ProgressPercentage` event argument, even though i state in `progress1()` that `percentage1 = e.ProgressPercentage`. And the progressBarAll does not move at all, even though i can see that the values for `percentage*` are all changing.

Comment: That's weird because you're not used to programming. You seem to be thinking of your code as of mathematical expressions. You expect that once you've written the code that averages the progresses, the relation should hold forever. However, c# is an [imperative programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming). It is just a sequence of commands for the machine: do this, then do that. Therefore, the averaging happens *only* when you click the `btnDldAll`. There are different techniques for making it work like math functions. I've presented one of them in my answer.

Comment: Well the main problem i'v been having learning C# is changing the way i think. Programming thought is quite different then what im used to doing. Its quite a challenge, but i'll get a hang of it cause StackOverflow has an awesome community that points out whats wrong and how to do it right. Thks for the help as well Aevitas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to think about 'using the event arguments outside the event'. Think about updating the state of your form.

Use properties to simplify the update logic:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
  private double percentage1;
  private double percentage2;
  private double percentage3;
  private double percentage4;
  private double percentage5;

  private double Percentage1 
  {
    get
    {
      return this.percentage1;
    }
    set
    {
      this.percentage1 = value;
      this.UpdatePercentageAll();  // this will update overall progress whenever the first one changes

      progressBar1.Value = GetValueFromPercentage(value);
    }
  }
  private double Percentage2
  // same code as for Percentage1

  void UpdatePercentageAll()
  {
    this.PercentageAll = (this.Percentage1 + this.Percentage2 + this.Percentage3 + this.Percentage4 + this.Percentage5) / 5;
  }

  static int GetValueFromPercentage(double percentage)
  {
    return (int)Math.Truncate(percentage);
  }

  double percentageAll;
  private double PercentageAll
  {
    get
    {
      return this.percentageAll;
    }
    set
    {
      this.percentageAll = value;

      progressBarAll.Value = GetValueFromPercentage(value);
    }
  }

  //Download File Async custom method
  public void DldFile(string url, string fileName, string localPath, AsyncCompletedEventHandler completedName, DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler progressName)
  {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), localPath + "\\" + fileName);
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(completedName);
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(progressName);
  }

  //Button 1 click event to start download
  private void btnDld1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (url1 != "" && Directory.Exists(localPath1))
    {
        this.StartDownloadFile1();
    }
    //took out the try/catch, other ifs to try and cut it down
  }
  void StartDownloadFile1()
  {
        this.Percentage1 = 0;
        _startDate1 = DateTime.Now;
        DldFile(url1, fileName1, localPath1, completed1, progress1);
  }
  //Download Progress Changed event for Download 1
  public void progress1(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.Percentage1 = e.ProgressPercentage; // update property, not field

    //this will be done in property setters
    //progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage1).ToString());
  }
  // then add similar code for other download buttons

  //Button that starts all downloads click event where all my problems are at the moment
  private void btnDldAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //Checks if the link exists and starts it from the download button click event
    if (url1 != "")
    {
        this.StartDownloadFile1();
    }
    //Continues for url2, 3, 4, 5 and else
  }
}
```

I would refactor the code even further, but I think it will be easier for you to understand if the code is closer to the original.

The main idea is to create a set of linked properties which work like mathematical functions. When writing the `PercentageX` properties I'm kind of saying 'let `PercentageAll` be the average of all percentages'. Then I have each download update it's own progress. Once any progress is updated it updates the average, *and I don't have to rememver that* inside the progress changed event handler.

And the last point is updating progress bars from percentage properties. It's quite straightforward: once a percentage is changed, I need to update a bar. If so, why bother writing something like

```
this.Percentage1 = x;
this.progressBar1.Value = (int)Math.Truncate(x);
```

In this case I have to remember everywhere that once I change the `Percentage1` I have to update the bar. And in my example I just create a strict rule for that which is only in one place and works everytime. So I just cannot forget it. And if I need to change the rule, I need to change only one place, so again I cannot make a mistake.

The technique I demonstrate can be expressed as a well-known rule: 'one rule - one place', which means that you should try to have only single place in code that expresses each logical rule that exists in your program. It is a very important idea, I suggest you learn and use it.

Comment: Pavel i dont quite understand the mechanics of the code you posted. I dont have any specific question about your post, im just too inexperienced to get it all at once. So im going to print this out, get everything understood, test it and then reply again. But im almost positive you'll get the accepted answer, thanks for the fast answer ;D

Comment: I just went through the code and i think you forgot to type in the `GetValueFromPercentage(value)` method. On the other hand and im not sure, but i have one progressBar per download + the progressBarAll, so the individual progressBars will move according to their own download, and the progressBarAll will move according to the total percentage of whatever downloads are happening. From reading your code i think you'r trying to use 1progressBar to inform any download happening. Let me know if i understood you correclty.

Comment: @FernandoSilva I'm sorry, I should have written a more complete code. I've just missed that `GetValueFromPercentage` method. And you're right, I've understood that you have only one progress bar for all downloads. I have update both the code and the answer. Please, check it out.

Comment: Well, i just put everything together and it works perfectly. Thanks for the help and patience Pavel. Now that i have this fixed (it was the only problem i was having) im going to release v.1.0 to the person that needs and asked for the application. Then i'll try to remake the whole code, cause i learnt a lot putting all this together, and i feel that there's a lot i would do diferently. I might even repost here all the tweeks and changes i made to get everything working. Thks again ;D

Comment: @ Pavel after pulling this off i got curious, when you say _I would refactor the code even further_ what do you mean by it? If its out-of-scope with this thread feel free to email me your suggestion. It would be appreciated, since im going to try and recode the whole thing for learning purposes.

Comment: I found another thing, the average doesnt return the desired value if there is less then the 5download running, so i made this `public int howManyDldsAreON; public int HowManyDldsAreON {get { return howManyDldsAreON; } set { howManyDldsAreON = value; UpdatePercentageAll(); }}` I implemented this `int` instead of `/5` and on btnDld1 `HowManyDldsAreON++` and on download completed event `HowManyDldsAreON--` Now it does what i want and with a property like you tought me ;D Thks^^